# How to retrieve the indexes of matched patterns in strings?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am looking for a pattern in a string. The pattern can be matched several time. How can I retrieve the index of each match ?

E.g. If I am looking for the pattern `al` in the string `albala` in need the values 0,3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class TestRegex
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("al");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("albala");
        while(m.find())
            System.out.println(m.start());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("al");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("albala");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.print("I found the text \"");
        System.out.print(matcher.group());
        System.out.print("\" starting at index ");
        System.out.print(matcher.start());
        System.out.print(" and ending at index ");
        System.out.print(matcher.end());
        System.out.print(".\n");
    }
}
```

You can find this example in [Test Harness (The Java Tutorials > Essential Classes > Regular Expressions)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html)